# Zend framework twitter api - media_id is like 5.5244895286041E+17

Tags: twitter, zend-framework2, image-uploading

Hello I have a strange problem(I am new in php and zend).
When trying to upload an image with twitter api, I am getting media_id like 5.5244895286041E+17.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

cast a `(string)` before setting the variable. The media_id most likely can't be represented as such a high floating number value. Consdiering its Twitter it mostlikely is a billion something.